# Como coletar tweets e followers pela API?

Tags: php, api, twitter-api

Bem galera estou aqui de novo pesquisando sobre as api's em redes sociais, estou iniciando o twitter agora e estou tendo algumas dificuldades, preciso coletar perfis (id/nome) e junto com o perfil tenho que coletar os tweets e os followers, até onde eu sei a linguagem que da pra fazer isso é em php, não conheço muito, mas acho que é uma linguagem mais comum. Alguém conhece algum tutorial claro que possa ajudar? ou algum trecho de código que possa ajudar?
Grato.

Comment: Faltou o mais importante. Em que linguagem? Aproveita coloca um contexto do que quer fazer. Leia o [tour] e o [ask].

Comment: Desculpa cara, acho que agora está mais claro.

Comment: Amigão da uma olhada nesse cara https://storm.apache.org/ estou usando ele no meu tcc .. é bem legal!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, sou o Luís, desenvolvedor evangelista do Twitter aqui no Brasil. O Twitter possui vários endpoints na API que permitem acessar o que você precisa. Não ficou claro a linguagem que você quer utilizar, mas vou dar o exemplo em PHP, já que você mencionou. Para conectar na API você precisa:

1. Criar uma app em apps.twitter.com
2. Obter as 4 chaves de acesso: consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret (na sua app em apps.twitter.com)
3. Configurar essas chaves na biblioteca que você vai utilizar:

A biblioteca mais recomendada para PHP é a tmhOAuth, veja um exemplo de como buscar tweets, disponível em https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples/blob/master/cli/search.php:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tmhOAuthExample.php';
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuthExample();
$code = $tmhOAuth->apponly_request(array(
  'method' => 'GET',
  'url' => $tmhOAuth->url('1.1/search/tweets'),
  'params' => array(
    'q' => 'tmhoauth'
  )
));
$tmhOAuth->render_response();
```

Você também pode obter o grafo de um usuário, como mostra o exemplo do mesmo repositório: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuthExamples/blob/master/cli/followings.php

Sugiro dar uma olhada nas seguintes referências:

- http://dev.twitter.com
- http://t.co/libs
- http://t.co/rest
- https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list
- https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

Comment: Luiz Boa Noite, eu estou tentando entender como trabalhar nessa questão mas ainda não estou entendendo como fazer a requisição pelo php, eu sei que precisa das keys e tokens, mas eu ainda não consegui coletar alguma coisa.